# google news json api (topic/headlines)

Tags: json, google-api

you probably all know the google news with headlines `https://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all`

there is also an json api for searching news: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q={query}` but i want to get the headlines or articles from one topic (e.g. technology).

i tried to add the parameters `pz=1&cf=all` but i have to give a search query `q=...`. Do you know if there is another way to get all headlines from Google News (JSON) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `q=*`, giving a URL like the following:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=*
```